# An animated TV show about a family of immortal kids kept alive by tea leaves

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a TV series maybe 15-20 years ago (around 2000-05?) that was about an immortal/very-long-lived family (on a farm?). I'm pretty sure it was a TV series, but it may have just been a long show (maybe a movie, but I doubt it).

- They were all kept really young because they grew and made tea with special tea leaves.
- I watched it when I was in Australia. I don't remember where the story was based.
- I seem to remember there was a lot of the colour
  blue in the show too? I think the tea was blue.
- I remember the story was pretty dark, but not
  gruesome or horror. Kind of creepy and mysterious.
- I think the animation visual style was kind of
  similar to the Gorillaz older art style.
- I'm pretty sure all (or most) characters were "white", and there were males and females.
- I think there were multiple generations of the family there. i.e. Kids through to grandparents. I remember that I got confused because they all looked the same age.
- I just remembered: I think the tea actually REVERSED their age, not just stopped them aging, because I vaguely remember a grandparent at one point that was younger than the kids temporarily because of a missed dose of tea or something.

Comment: Since you mention Gorillaz, is this an animated series then?

Comment: And were you in Australia when you watched it? Was the show set in Australia? Both?

Comment: Very partial match (if live action) at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Islands

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes, it was animated. Sorry, forgot to actually say that. I was in Aus when I watched. I don't know where it was, story-wise. Its interesting that that live-action one does sound oddly similar, but no, it was definately animated and set inland, not on an island or coastal. I'm pretty sure it was on a farm

Comment: Please see if [this checklist of tips for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) triggers any more memories you could edit in, to increase the chances of a successful ID :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the series I was looking for by random luck this morning. It is called "[Deadly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadly_(Australian_TV_series))" and was shown 2006-10. Thanks to those who helped find it.

> It's hard work when you're twelve years old, and have to look after your mother – who has just turned two. It's frustrating being a runaway in search of your family – with only a faded photo to go on. And it's absolutely DEADLY knowing that the seeds of a blue tea plant have been washed into the river system, and any moment now plants will grow that can keep people young forever.
>
> But at least Amy and Sprocket have each other. Together they'll bring up Toddler Mum as best they can, they'll fight Pooper Scooper and his malevolent family, and they'll end every one of those mutating tea plants before they can destroy the world.